# MySql Reverse LIKE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have white listed URLs in `urls` table in the following format

```
---domain---
website1.com
website2.com
website3.com
website4.com
```

And PHP variable `$url` consists of the following URL:

```
http://www.website2.com/path/tp/some/file.php
```

So, I want to check if the `$url` is of white listed domain or not. Here is the query (reverse LIKE clause) that I wrote. but, its not correct syntax

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM urls WHERE '".$url."' LIKE %domain%")or die(mysql_error());
```

is there any way to achieve this in a single query?

Comment: what you mean single query? Its already single.

Comment: This would mean each of your URLs has a column named after it in your table.  I doubt this is the case.  Also, you need to put tick-marks (\`) around column names, not single quotes (').

Comment: @imsiso Single query means, I don't wanna fetch all the white-listed domains and match one by one in another query or one by one in `php` loop.

Comment: @CullyLarson I've tried this thing as well, but syntax error. My table has two columns `id` and `domain`.. usually, we do search like this
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column LIKE '%keywords%'`
But, in my case, `column` comes after the `'%keywords%'`

Comment: `http://www.website2.com/path/tp/some/file.php` is not the name of one of your columns, so you can't refer to is as a column name.  Why do you want to do it this way, in any case?

Comment: Why not:  `SELECT * FROM urls WHERE domain LIKE '%{$url}%'` ?

Comment: Though, in any case, you should be using mysqli, prepared statements, and data binding.  The old mysql functions are deprecated.

Comment: because, it'll always return the empty result.
`$url = 'http://www.website2.com/path/tp/some/file.php'` and 
`domain is 'website2.com'`
in short, in your suggested solution, the actual query would be like

`SELECT * FROM urls WHERE domain LIKE '%http://www.website2.com/path/tp/some/file.php%'`
here, if domain column is `website2.com` it can never be `http://www.website2.com/path/tp/some/file.php` because, domain is already the Sub String of the url.

Comment: hence, we need to put `%` around column name instead of `url`

Comment: `domain` is the name of the column.  `website2.com` is one value in that column, it isn't the name of the column.  I'll post an answer that should probably work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `CONCAT` syntax

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM urls WHERE '".$url."' LIKE CONCAT('%', domain, '%')")or die(mysql_error());
```

and then you can check if the query returned any result or not.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the column name you meant to use.

```
$url = 'http://www.website2.com/path/tp/some/file.php';
$parse = parse_url($url);


mysql_query("SELECT if( count(id) > 0, true, false ) as whitelisted FROM urls WHERE domain = '".$parse['host']."'")or die(mysql_error());
```

This little if statement and the count will ensure you that you will get a true/false value out if the query, as $array["whitelisted"] if the $parse['host'] is in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Not that easy I think why you don't use PHP to get the domain part of `$url`?

Like:

```
<?php
$url='http://www.website2.com/path/tp/some/file.php';
$aurl=parse_url($url);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($aurl);

/* //output will be like this.
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.website2.com
    [path] => /path/tp/some/file.php
)
*/
$host=$aurl['host']
?>
```

And you can have your query with this:

```
$query="SELECT id FROM urls WHERE domain LIKE '%{$host}%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to search for the domain name of the urls you have.  Try something like this:

```
$url = "http://www.website2.com/path/tp/some/file.php";

$urlInfo = parse_url($url); // this is a standard PHP function, see php.net/parse_url

$domain = $urlInfo['host'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE domain LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", "%" + $domain + "%");
$stmt->execute();
```

This example extracts just the domain name from your URL and searches using it.  It also uses mysqli, which you should try to use instead of the mysql functions (which are deprecated).  Using your code snippet for the actual query would look like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM urls WHERE domain LIKE '%{$domain}%'");
```

Also, since your table contains domain names, you might not even need to use `LIKE`.  `=` could suffice.